# Problem that file locations open in the browser instead of the expected File Manager

Tags: nautilus, files, browser

I'm having a problem with file locations opening in the default *browser* (Firefox) instead of the expected *File Manager*.

Experience level 4/10

Running Ubuntu 16.04/Xerus with Unity desktop since June 2016 (running Ubuntu distros for years.)  Beginning about two months after upgrade to Xerus, clicking on the Trash icon in launcher opens a *browser* window with "trash:///" in the search field for Google (default search engine) and the respective search results displayed, instead of opening the File Manager (Nautilus) windows as always before.

Related, I have text documents (Word/Writer) with many hyperlinks to file locations in my computer.  For years, the hyperlinks correctly opened the file location displaying in "File Manager".  Now the hyperlinks open browser windows displaying the folders & files, much like an FTP.

Two functions that still work correctly are clicking on the main File Manager icon in the launch bar, or clicking on any Folder on my Desktop, both of which open File Manager as expected.

The inode/directory  in  /usr/share/applications/defaults.list shows:  nautilus-file-handler.desktop (as it should-?)

Searching for "Trash"  in my system results in the following location: 
file:///usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/en/kcontrol/

I'm a bit confused as to why I would have KDE reference in the path when I'm running Ubuntu Xerus/Unity (and the "HTML" in the link - ?) (Obviously I'm not an expert.)

No doubt that a reinstall of Xerus would correct this folder opening problem, but I would really like to learn how to correct this instead of reinstalling.

Thanks

Comment: Solved - figured it out myself:   In the . . . applications/mimeapps.list, I changed:  "inode/directory=firefox.desktop" 
to  "inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop", and it corrected the problem.